# get data by ajax

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, google-translate

I am using Translate Google. the page I am using `$.ajax` to get data. Now when the page with a Google translation of the text that I've been with `$.ajax`does not translate. When I get the `view source` browser does not show any text in the text are normally head.

**HTML**

```
<div id="holdershortabout"></div>
```

**Script**

```
$.ajax({ url: "Allcammand.aspx?cmd=GetProperty",
                async: false ,
                   success: function(response){
                           $("#holder").html(response);                                                                           
                    },
                    error:function(){}
            });
```

this code is run success and show data in `holder` but when click on `view/PageSource` in browser does not show any text in `holder`?????

Comment: You are missing a `"` at the end of your url

Comment: FYI, Google translate is deprecating soon! rather wasting time developing by Google translate I would suggest migrate to Yahoo translate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Page source wont contain dynamic data. Means data manipulated by javascript. See it through firebug to see the content.